# Schengen visa aplication: cost of travelling reimbursed

Tags: schengen-visas, visa-sponsors

I am filling out the application form for a Schengen visa and am a bit unsure how to answer q. 32:

Cost of travelling and living during the applicant’s stay is covered: by the applicant / by a sponsor.

I will pay for the tickets, hotels, and all living expenses using my credit card and will then be reimbursed by the company that is sending me to this trip (the reimbursement will be performed after returning from the trip). Does this count as "covered by the applicant" or "by a sponsor"?

Comment: Obviously sponsor.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, get the company sponsoring you to include confirmation in their invitation letter that they are covering your costs via reimbursement

Comment: @AnishSheela, just to clarify, I will be reimbursed only after I come back from the trip, so during the whole travel I will be paying by myself. Would it still count as sponsorship?

Comment: @Traveller, yes, I can get a letter mentioning reimbursement from the company that sends me to the trip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So finally in my application I checked both boxes and indicated that I will use my credit card and that the company will reimburse the expenses. I recently got my visa so this approach seems to have worked out fine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the experience. Please mark one of the answers as accepted.

Comment: @AnishSheela ok. I guess I will accept my own answer then since this is exactly what I did

Answer (score 3):

This is the standard process for most of the trips sponsored by companies. You have to pay, either with a corporate credit card or a personal one. Company will reimburse based on expense claims. So, yes, your **trip is sponsored by the company**, even though you are paying at the moment.

Let me tell the rationale behind this. The country you are visiting just wants to know whether you are there on a legitimate purpose and will be going back at the end of the trip. For a business event with a reputed company, a certain level of legitimacy is already established. So, the immigration agents will allow you, even if your bank balance is not that great, as its sponsored by company.

Get a letter from your company saying that they are sponsoring the trip and attach it with the application.